# registering to events with google publisher tag

Tags: google-dfp

according to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent

there should be a way to register to an event that a tag was rendered:

> **Class googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent**
>
> This event is fired when a slot on the page has finished rendering.

but when i inspected the dfp object i don't see any event namespace

[image]

any idea how to register to this event?

Comment: What exactly is your problem or question? Doesn't it work? Why do you expect an event namespace? I can confirm it works.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to register to the event. maybe i missed that documentation. i would be happy if you can share a code that shows how

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To register the event, use the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
    googletag.defineSlot('/123456/leadeboard', [[728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-123456789-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); 
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
      console.log('Slot has been rendered:');
    });
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

The documentation is found in the [GPT reference](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.Service_addEventListener).

Comment: @CodoHow can i remove this eventListener ,I am doing below code but its not working googletag.pubads().removeEventListener('slotRenderEnded')

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an API to do it. Why would you want to do it anyway?

Comment: I want it because when it attached it will call on every slot and call its callback on every slot which dont needed .so i want to remove this listener .any solution ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: may i add this event listener to a particular slot ??

Comment: Is it necessary to add an event listener inside googletag.cmd.push?

Comment: `googletag.cmd.push` is Google's way of delaying the execution of these commands until the GPT Javascript file has been loaded asynchronously. This is a good thing as it doesn't delay the loading and display of your website as most ad servers do. If you know that the GPT Javascript file has already been loaded, you do not need `googletag.cmd.push`. If you omit it but the Javascript file hasn't been loaded yet, an error will occur.