# Google Publisher Tag, how to remove event listener from Service

Tags: google-publisher-tag

There seem to be several questions on how to register events to a gpt service:
[Google Publisher Tag registering to Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154738/google-publisher-tag-registering-to-events)
[registering to events with google publisher tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792393/registering-to-events-with-google-publisher-tag)

How to do this is clearly defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.Service):
`googletag.pubads().addEventListener('eventName', callbackFn);`

I add my event to the service when the component (React) mounts inside the callback function of `window.googletag.cmd.push` as described in [this tutorial by Google](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2694377?hl=en).

Now the problem is that every time I change page, more event listeners are added to the service. I can make sure only one event listener executes on the actually existing slots by using this method (from the documentation):

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('impressionViewable', function(event) {
  if (event.slot == targetSlot) { // will only run on target slot
    // Slot specific logic.
  }
});
```

But more an more event listeners will remain active and keep on executing (without executing the code within the if-statement).

Now, I assumed google would have implemented something like this (to run on componentWillUnmount):
`googletag.pubads().removeEventListener('eventName', callbackFn);`

But it doesn't exist in the documentation and I can't seem to find any way to remove active event listeners from the service?

Comment: I have the same problem. Found no way/document

Answer (score 2):

So I went with this:

```
let eventListnerCreated = false;
if(!eventListnerCreated) {
    eventListnerCreated = googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotRenderEnded", function(event) {
          // blablabla
    });
}
```

Not clean. But will work.

I know this doesn't solve the original issue of removing the event listener, but this will let's not create event listeners again and again.